# vrchat-api код не могу заставить работать

Tags: python, api

Код взял отсюда:

```
> Цитата

https://vscode.githubhelp.com/7ew1r/vrchat-api-python/blob/HEAD/examples/who_blocked_me.py#L1-L43

Работаю в PyCharm



 #!/usr/bin/env python3

from getpass import getpass

from vrchat_api import VRChatAPI
from vrchat_api.enum import ModerationType

"""
Show a list of users who have blocked you.
"""

a = VRChatAPI(
    getpass("VRChat Username"),
    getpass()
)
a.authenticate()

moderations = a.getModerations()
blockModerations = filter(
    lambda x: x.type == ModerationType.BLOCK,
    moderations
)
unblockModerations = filter(
    lambda x: x.type == ModerationType.UNBLOCK,
    moderations
)

for m in blockModerations:
    s = "{:20} blcoked me at {} ...".format(
        m.targetDisplayName,
        m.created
    )
    unblocks = list(filter(
        lambda x: x.targetDisplayName == m.targetDisplayName,
        unblockModerations
    ))
    if len(unblocks) > 0:
        latestUnblock = unblocks[-1]
        if latestUnblock.created > m.created:
            s += " but he/she unblocked at {}".format(latestUnblock.created)

    print(s)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При попытке выполнить скрипт получаю эти ошибки: C:\Users\Volkent\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Volkent\PycharmProjects\test\test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Volkent\PycharmProjects\test\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    from vrchat_api import VRChatAPI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vrchat_api'

Process finished with exit code 1
Все зависимости скачал и библиотеки